# Mqsql Query question

Tags: php, sql, database

sorry i am a sql noob.

I have 2 tables:

```
Customer:
customerid - int, pri-key,auto
fname - varchar
sname -varchar
housenum - varchar
streetname -varchar

items
itemid - int,pri-key,auto
type - varchar
collectiondate - date
releasedate - date
customerid - int
```

I need a sql query which will get me all items for a given customer including some customer details, specifically: fname + sname + type + collectiondate + releasedate + housenum + streetname.

for example, if joe bloggs has 5 items then 5 rows will be returned and the columns will be as described above

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.customerid, fname, sname, type, collectiondate, releasedate, housenum, streetname 
from customer as a
inner join items as b on b.customerid = a.customerid
```

**Update  #1**

```
    select a.customerid, fname, sname, type, collectiondate, releasedate, housenum, streetname 
    from customer as a
    inner join items as b on b.customerid = a.customerid
where a.customerid = 4 //or whatever number or variable
```

Comment: im confused, i cant see any where clause...in my situation, the user chooses a customerid from a combobox and then executes the query, where in your query would i provide this customerid? usually i would do smt like SELECT fname FROM customer where customerid = 5

Comment: @brux Just add the WHERE clause, as you described, beneath the INNER JOIN clause...

Answer (score 1):

```
select customer.*,
       items.*
   from
       customer,
       items
   where
       customer.customerid = items.customerid
   order by
       customer.customerID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.fname, c.sname, i.type, i.collectiondate, i.releasedate, c.housenum, c.streetname
from customers c inner join items i
on c.customerid = i.customerid
```

It is generally not recommended to use "*" because then your returned dataset will change if a new column is ever added to the table, and because it makes you dependent on the order of columns in the table, whether specifying the column names by yourself leaves all the control in your hands and makes the application more flexible to changes.

Besides, it is better to specifically use JOIN than just list the table names.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but i cant seem to find a way to pass the costomerid (in my case chosen in a combobox) into the query so that it returns rows for that particular customer, how would i modify your code so i can do this?

Comment: If you want only the data for customer with ID 500, just add the following in the end of the query:
where customerid = 500